# Reuse selected options in Reach-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-select to create a logical expression and save it in array(the data I use ). Code as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
 
function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      value: and,
      label: "AND"
    },
    {
      value: or,
      label: "OR"
    },
    {
      value: A,
      label: "A"
    },
    {
      value: B,
      label: "B"
    },
    {
      value: C,
      label: "C"
    }
  ];
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedValue(Array.isArray(e) ? e.map(x => x.value) : []);
  }
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        className="dropdown"
        placeholder="Select Option"
        value={data.filter(obj => selectedValue.includes(obj.value))} // set selected values
        options={data} // set list of the data
        onChange={handleChange} // assign onChange function
        isMulti
        isClearable
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
      />
 
      {selectedValue && <div style={{ marginTop: 20, lineHeight: '25px' }}>
        <div><b>Selected Value: </b> {JSON.stringify(selectedValue, null, 2)}</div>
      </div>}
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

It works well when using options once such as creating `A and B`, but is there any solutions for creating `A and B and C` by reusing `and` option?
Here's what I'm thinking right now:

1. When select operator'and' or 'or', prevent selected them but only update the `selectedValue` Array instead. But is there a way I could see the selected options in multi-select part as well?
2. Make the operator options dynamic to make it unique(maybe use Date()?), but it would also mess up the options data?
   Would be appreciated if there's any better solution

Comment: can I know what you are trying to achieve? You want to display [A][AND][B][And][C] ?

Comment: Yes I want to get [A][AND][B][AND][C]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure your purpose, but I would suggest to treat your "AND" and "OR" in your data object as a temporary value. Then replace it with something you want to display.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {

    setSelectedValue(Array.isArray(e) ? 
         e.map(x => {
             let temp;  
             if (x.value === 'AND') return 'and'
             if (x.value === 'OR') return 'or'
             return x.value
     }) : []);
}
```

Your selected array will be ['A','and','B','and','C'];

This way the AND and OR are still available for selection. This is just an idea, you need to work on it.

Comment: In this way the selectedValue could be set correctly, but will the multi-select part display as expected?

Comment: There's a data props and a value props.

Comment: You mean set the SelectedValue in data prop and use an API to set the display value(value prop) in react-select?

Comment: I may get your point, you mean that react-select is using different API for `options` prop and `value` prop and only need uniqueness for `value`, so we can put temp value and add a function to change it back when display, right?